# Plot a density function above a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

In Python, I have estimated the parameters for the density of a model of my distribution and I would like to plot the density function above the histogram of the distribution. In R it is similar to using the option `prop=TRUE`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# initialization of the list "data"
# estimation of the parameter, in my case, mean and variance of a normal distribution

plt.hist(data, bins="auto") # data is the list of data
# here I would like to draw the density above the histogram
plt.show()
```

I guess the trickiest part is to make it fit.

**Edit:** I have tried this according to the first answer:

```
mean = np.mean(logdata)
var  = np.var(logdata)
std  = np.sqrt(var) # standard deviation, used by numpy as a replacement of the variance
plt.hist(logdata, bins="auto", alpha=0.5, label="données empiriques")
x = np.linspace(min(logdata), max(logdata), 100)
plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x, mean, std))
plt.xlabel("log(taille des fichiers)")
plt.ylabel("nombre de fichiers")
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't fit the graph, here is how it looks: [image: What I get with the python code above. I would like the density to fit the histogram but the values are too small.]

** Edit 2 ** Works with the option `normed=True` in the histogram function.
[image: Something that would look like this (done in R with the optionprob=TRUE)]

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. Can you add screenshots/more information on how you would like the figure to look? As always, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would massively help your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Here it is. Yes, you are right an example is better than a thousand explications ! But still I thought my explication was pretty clear...

Comment: I have added a solution if you don't want to use `normed = True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have the mean and standard deviation of some data. You have plotted a histogram of this and would like to plot the normal distribution line over the histogram. This line can be generated using `matplotlib.mlab.normpdf()`, the documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 100
sigma = 5

data = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,1000) # generate fake data
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 100)

plt.hist(data, bins="auto",normed=True)
plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x, mean, sigma))

plt.show()
```

Which gives the following figure:

[image]

**Edit:** The above only works with `normed = True`. If this is not an option, we can define our own function:

```
def gauss_function(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

mean = 100
sigma = 5

data = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,1000) # generate fake data
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)

test = gauss_function(x, max(data), mean, sigma)

plt.hist(data, bins="auto")
plt.plot(x, test)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you are looking for, already are in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html).

You just have to use `distplot`

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(5, 2, size=1000)
sns.distplot(data)
```

[image: plot is here]