# Draw the density curve exactly on the Histogram without normalizing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, boxplot

I need to draw the density curve on the Histogram with the actual height of the bars (actual frequency) as the y-axis.

*Try1:*
I found a related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889189/plot-a-density-function-above-a-histogram) but, it has normalized the Histogram to the range of the curve.

Below is my code and the output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

data = [125.36, 126.66, 130.28, 133.74, 126.92, 120.85, 119.42, 128.61, 123.53, 130.15, 126.02, 116.65, 125.24, 126.84,
        125.95, 114.41, 138.62, 127.4, 127.59, 123.57, 133.76, 124.6, 113.48, 128.6, 121.04, 119.42, 120.83, 136.53, 120.4,
        136.58, 121.73, 132.72, 109.25, 125.42, 117.67, 124.01, 118.74, 128.99, 131.11, 112.27, 118.76, 119.15, 122.42,
        122.22, 134.71, 126.22, 130.33, 120.52, 126.88, 117.4]
(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 100)

plt.hist(data, bins=12, normed=True)
plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))

plt.show()
```

[image: Result when normed is True]
*Try2:*
[There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889189/plot-a-density-function-above-a-histogram) @DavidG has given an option, a user defined function even it doesn't cover the density of the Histogram accurately.

```
def gauss_function(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))
test = gauss_function(x, max(data), mu, sigma)

plt.hist(data, bins=12)
plt.plot(x, test)
plt.show()
```

The result for this was,
[image]
But the actual Histogram is below, where Y-axis ranges from 0 to 8,
[image]
And I want to draw the density curve exactly on that. Any help this regards will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm multiplying the pdf by the area of the histogram.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

data = [125.36, 126.66, 130.28, 133.74, 126.92, 120.85, 119.42, 128.61, 123.53, 130.15, 126.02, 116.65, 125.24, 126.84,
        125.95, 114.41, 138.62, 127.4, 127.59, 123.57, 133.76, 124.6, 113.48, 128.6, 121.04, 119.42, 120.83, 136.53, 120.4,
        136.58, 121.73, 132.72, 109.25, 125.42, 117.67, 124.01, 118.74, 128.99, 131.11, 112.27, 118.76, 119.15, 122.42,
        122.22, 134.71, 126.22, 130.33, 120.52, 126.88, 117.4]

(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(data)
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 100)

values, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=12)
area = sum(np.diff(bins) * values)

plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma) * area, 'r')
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted. Thanx a lot for your effort.